# SQL server select statement to select the ids of a duplicated entries of another column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Consider the table 'Table1' as below

```
main_id         main_item_id
--------        ---------
1                    101
1                    102
2                    105
2                    105
3                    105
3                    106
4                    101
4                    101
4                    102
```

I need to fetch main_id 2 and 4 as it has duplicate main_item_id among 1 million other records

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will select all unique main_id's which have 2 or more identical main_item_id's:

```
SELECT   DISTINCT T.main_id
FROM     YourTable T
GROUP BY T.main_id
,        T.Main_item_id
HAVING   COUNT(1) > 1
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked for me. It took 50 seconds to fetch from over a million records.

Answer (score 1):

Use `group by` clause to check the duplication

```
SELECT main_id, main_item_id 
FROM table
GROUP BY main_id, main_item_id 
HAVING count(*) > 1
```